# Is it possible to retrieve all available chart templates in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm currently working on Word add-in using VSTO and have custom logic for chart insertion. I want to show a user a dialog with all available chart template with preview like Word does. Where Word stores chart templates and how can I retrieve them all? Is it possible to get a preview of all these charts?

Answer (score 3):

The AddChart method takes an Enum of Type Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType.  You can get the values of the enum using the Enum.GetNames method.  Then you can parse the value the user selected to use it with the AddChart method.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
     listBox1.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType)));
    }

    private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType enumVal = (Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType)Enum.Parse(typeof(Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType), listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddChart(enumVal);
        }
    }
```

Getting a preview might be a little bit trickier.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to me that there is no any trivial way to get a preview, so I have to associate each chart type with icon manually.

Comment: I have dug around and have yet to find a way to display the chart dialog or get at its underlying images.